# this.props Not Returning Fetched Data From Parent Component (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to render playlist information for an Audio Player in React. The data is coming from a fetch call in the parent component (PostContent.js). The data being returned is an array of objects that looks like:
[ {name: ‘track name’, artist: ‘artist name’, url: ’https://blahblah.wav', lrc: ‘string’, theme: ‘another string’ }, {…}, {…}, etc. }

I am not able to return the data in the render() method of the child component (AudioPlayer.js). When I console.log(this.props.audio) in the render(), my terminal prints three responses. The first is an empty array, and the next two are the correct data that I need (an array of objects).

How can I set the props on the ‘audio’ key in the ‘props’ object in the render() method of the AudioPlayer.js component?

I should mention that I am using the react-aplayer library, and I am able to make this work with hard-coded data, as in the example here (https://github.com/MoePlayer/react-aplayer), but I am trying to make a dynamic playlist component for a blog website. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

AudioPlayer.js (Child Component)

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactAplayer from '../react-aplayer';
import './AudioPlayer.css';
import sample from '../../src/adrian_trinkhaus.jpeg';


export default class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  // event binding example
  onPlay = () => {
    console.log('on play');
  };

  onPause = () => {
    console.log('on pause');
  };

  // example of access aplayer instance
  onInit = ap => {
    this.ap = ap;
  };

  render() {
    console.log('props in render of AudioPlayer', this.props.audio)
    const props = {
      theme: '#F57F17',
      lrcType: 3,
      audio: this.props.audio
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactAplayer
          {...props}
          onInit={this.onInit}
          onPlay={this.onPlay}
          onPause={this.onPause}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PostContent.js (Parent Component)

```
import React, { Component, useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import AudioPlayer from './AudioPlayer';

export default class PostContent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: '',
      episodeData: [],
      audio: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/episode/${id}/playlist`);
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    const songs = jsonData;
    const audio = Object.keys(songs).map(key => {
      return {
        name: songs[key].name,
        artist: songs[key].artist,
        url: songs[key].url,
        cover: songs[key].cover,
        lrc: songs[key].lrc,
        theme: songs[key].theme
      }
    });
    this.setState({ audio })
  }


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.audio !== this.state.audio) {
      const newAudio = this.state.audio;
      this.setState({ audio: newAudio }, () => console.log('new audio', this.state.audio))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <AudioPlayer audio={this.state.audio} />
        <Link id='home-link' to='/' activeClassName='active'>Homepage</Link>
        {this.state.episodeData.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="word-content">
            <h2 className="show-title">{item.post_title}</h2>
            <div className="episode-post-content">
              <p>{item.post_content1}</p>
              <p>{item.post_content2}</p>
              <p>{item.post_content3}</p></div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Table data={this.state.data} />
        <div className="bottom-link">
          <Link id='home-link' to='/' activeClassName='active'>Homepage</Link>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i played around with an async scenario with  your code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-lichterman-bx959?file=/src/AudioPlayer.js)

i think the problem is when you're trying to access the payload in `ReactAPlayer` component when audio it's not loaded yet from the async call. what you need to do is only use "audio" when it's valid like this `if (audio.length) {...}` or `audio && ...` some form of check to prevent it from being accessed in the reactAplayer render function.

fyi - you can remove the `componentDidUpdate` hook, since you have a `setState` call inside the ...Didmount hook, when `setState` is called inside ...didMount, the component calls its `render()` thus trigger a child re-render and its child will do the same..

Comment: Thanks so much! I put a conditional operator around the <ReactAPlayer /> component and that did the trick. So it looks like: {props.audio.length > 0 ? <ReactAPlayer {...props} /> : <p>no data</p>}.  Thanks again for the help - I have been trying to figure this out all day!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it doesnt work because you set this.props inside a props obejct, so maybe you need to do something like

```
var that = this 
const props = {
  audio = that.props.audio 
}
```

Comment: Oh, nice. Thanks for that! I put that in, but it looks like it may be an issue with the data from the fetch. When I console.log(props) just above the return(), I get three responses. The first response doesn't include the audio key/values. The next two do include them. Is there a way to make sure that the props are set on the audio key before the return is rendered?